# C++ Program not executing properly, may be a scope issue

Tags: c++, scope

I'm working on creating a C++ program that's simply a Shell Game. I'm having an issue where if the user's guess is incorrect and they guess again, it doesn't check the guess again. Instead, it just returns to the main menu. I'm guessing this must be a scope issue, but I'm not too sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <array>

using namespace std;

void displayMenu();
void displayGameMenu ();


int main() {
int userChoice;
int n;
do {
    int incorrectGuess;
    displayMenu();
    cin >> userChoice;
    if (userChoice == 1) {
        displayGameMenu();
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 3) {
            cout << "The minimum number of cups is 3. Please enter the amount of cups you'd like to play with: " << endl;
            cin >> n;
        }
        else {
            bool cups[n];
            cout << "The game is ready, and the ball is under one of the " << n << " cups. Guess which cup the ball is in: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << "Cup " << i + 1 << "\n";
            }
            cout << "Enter -1 to leave the game. ";
            int ballLocation = rand()%(n-3) + 3;
            cups[ballLocation] = true;
            int userGuess;
            cin >> userGuess;
            if (userGuess == ballLocation) {
                cout << "Congrats! You win! What would you like to do now?\n";
                return 0;
            }
            else if (userGuess != ballLocation) {

                cout << "Nope! Not it! Try again: \n";
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    cout << "Cup " << i + 1 << "\n";
                }
                cout << "Enter -1 to leave the game. ";
                cin >> userGuess;
                ballLocation = rand()%(n-3) + 3;
                incorrectGuess++;
            }
            else if (userGuess > n) {
                cout << "Invalid guess! Try again: ";
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    cout << "Cup " << i + 1 << "\n";
                }
                cout << "Enter -1 to leave the game. ";
                cin >> userGuess;
            }
            else if (incorrectGuess == 4) {
                cout << "You're out of guesses! Nice try! \n";
                return 0;
            }
            else if ( userGuess == -1) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
    while (userChoice != 2);

}
void displayMenu() {
cout << "Welcome to the Shell Game! Please choose one of the menu options   below.\n";
cout << "1. Play the Game!\n";
cout << "2. Quit.\n";
cout << "Enter choice here: " << endl;
}

void displayGameMenu() {
cout << "Thank you for deciding to play the Shell Game. How many cups (3 is the minimum) would you like to play with? " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop will perform everything in the scope brackets before it:

```
do
{
   // EVERYthing in here is performed within the while loop
} while ();
```

Now have a look at your scope:

```
do
{
    ...
    displayMenu();
    ...
} while (userChoice != 2);
```

Do you see the problem yet? You are telling your `while` loop to display the menu each iteration of the loop! You probably want to put `displayMenu()` before the `do while`